# Passar sequência de passos (métodos) para window (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, paralelismo

Saudações...atualmente possuo uma tela semelhante a apresentada abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa tela utiliza BackgroundWorker para executar uma sequência de passos e informar ao usuário através das mensagens no textblock um passo a passo das tarefas que estão sendo executadas no momento.

Após o término do último passo, os botões de log e fechar são apresentados e a ProgressBar(abaixo dos botões) é parada, informando assim o término do processamento.

Gostaria de reaproveitar essa tela para outras operações, cujo número de passos, cada operação terá o seu, então não sei como exemplificar, mas gostaria de passar pra tela uma operação com vários passos a ser executado, em outro momento passaria outra operação com vários outros passos...quero reaproveitar as funcionalidades de salvar log e informar o usuário passo a passo.

Pensei em algo conforme as classes abaixo, porém não sei por onde começar:

```
public class Operacao1
{
    public void Inicia()
    {
        // Gostaria de atualizar a tela aqui!
        Passo1();
        // Aguarda a finalização do passo 1
        Passo2();
        // Aguarda a finalização do passo 2
        Passo3();
        // Gostaria de atualizar a tela aqui!
    }

    private void Passo1()
    {
        // Gostaria de atualizar a tela aqui!
        // implemento a funcionalidade...
        // Atualizo novamente a tela aqui!
    }

    private void Passo2()
    {
        // Gostaria de atualizar a tela aqui!
        // implemento a funcionalidade...
        // Atualizo novamente a tela aqui!
    }

    private void Passo3()
    {
        // Gostaria de atualizar a tela aqui!
        // implemento a funcionalidade...
        // Atualizo novamente a tela aqui!
    }
}

public class Operacao2
{
    public void Inicia()
    {
        // Gostaria de atualizar a tela aqui!
        Passo1();
        // Aguarda a finalização do passo 1
        Passo2();
        // Gostaria de atualizar a tela aqui!
    }

    private void Passo1()
    {
        // Gostaria de atualizar a tela aqui!
        // implemento a funcionalidade...
        // Atualizo novamente a tela aqui!
    }

    private void Passo2()
    {
        // Gostaria de atualizar a tela aqui!
        // implemento a funcionalidade...
        // Atualizo novamente a tela aqui!
    }
}
```

Queria um norte pra saber se com o BackgroundWorker daria certo, ou se teria que usar task, etc...agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Seguinte Paulo, o que entendi é que você deseja uma tela reaproveitável, tentarei te dar um luz para você dar continuidade.

Primeiro, deixa eu tirar essa sua dúvida abaixo:

> Queria um norte pra saber se com o BackgroundWorker daria certo, ou se teria que usar task, etc...agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Como o Stephen Cleary explica no seu Blog: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html

> BackgroundWorker is a type that should not be used in new code. Everything it can do, Task.Run can do better; and Task.Run can do a lot of things that BackgroundWorker can’t!

Lendo o artigo fica mais claro que o BackgroundWorker pode, até mesmo deve, ser substituído pelo Task. Lembrando que o artigo é de 2013, faz 4 anos que isso foi mencionado.

Sobre o seu problema, fiz a seguinte resolução:

Criei um `UserControl` contendo:

*UserControl1.xaml*

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="OPERANDO" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="40">
        <StackPanel x:Name="spResultado" Background="White">

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

O código do UserControl

*UserControl1.cs*

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public async Task<bool> ExecutaAcao(Func<bool> Acao)
    {
        Task<bool> task = new Task<bool>(Acao);
        task.Start();
        await task;
        return task.Result;
    }

    public void InformaAcao(string value)
    {
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock { Text = value };
        spResultado.Children.Add(txt);
    }

    public void ExibeResultado(string value)
    {
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock { Text = value, Foreground = Brushes.Green };
        spResultado.Children.Add(txt);
    }

}
```

O nosso UserControl está pronto para receber as informações (lembrando que isso é apenas um exemplo).

A ideia é colocar esse UserControl onde precisar e passar as informações para ele processar.

Na Interface sua `Window` adicione ele:

*Window.xaml*

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="UserControl1"/>
```

No código da sua `Window` ele ficará assim assim:

*Window.cs*

```
 //CRIA UM FUNC QUE RETORNARÁ TRUE OU FALSO PARA 
        Func<bool> baixaArquivos = new Func<bool>(() =>
        {
            // SEU PROCEDIMENTO AQUI
            // REMOVER ESSE THREAD.SLEEP, COLOQUEI ELE APENAS PARA SEGURAR O PROCESSO POR 5s
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            // CASO SEU PROCEDIMENTO TEVE SUCESSO, RETORNE TRUE
            return true;
        });

        Func<bool> removeArquivos = new Func<bool>(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return true;
        });
        Func<bool> instalaSistema = new Func<bool>(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return true;
        });

        //INFORMA O USUARIO SOBRE QUAL PROCESSO ESTÁ SENDO EXECUTADO
        UserControl1.InformaAcao("Inicia processo de download do arquivo");
        //EXECUTA DE MANEIRA ASSINCRÓNICA A FUNC CRIADA ACIMA E RETORNA O STATUS
        if (await UserControl1.ExecutaAcao(baixaArquivos) == true) { UserControl1.ExibeResultado("Sucesso no download"); } else { MessageBox.Show("Erro na operação"); return; }


        UserControl1.InformaAcao("Remove antigos arquivos");
        if (await UserControl1.ExecutaAcao(removeArquivos) == true) { UserControl1.ExibeResultado("Sucesso na remoção dos arquivos"); } else { MessageBox.Show("Erro na operação"); return; }
        UserControl1.InformaAcao("Instalando novo sistema");
        if (await UserControl1.ExecutaAcao(instalaSistema) == true) { UserControl1.ExibeResultado("Sucesso ao instalar sistema"); } else { MessageBox.Show("Erro na operação"); return; }
```

Esse foi só um exemplo, tem outras maneiras de fazer isso. Você pode fazer com ou sem o `UserControl`, fica o seu critério. Pode também passar uma `Action` ou alguma outra coisa no lugar do Func.

Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.
Boa Sorte